# How to set a 404 error page on wordpress/fishpig for magento

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I've done a fully integration of a Wordpress in a Magento shop with FishPig, everything is working fine except that I can't find where or how to find/edit/set a custom 404 error page.
It's my first time using Magento and my php knowledge is very limited so any help would be much appreciated. 
Btw, That's the default no-route error I get: http://doshaburi.com/blog/category/xx/
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible via a configuration setting in the extension. What you could do though, is include a .phtml file in your 404 page and then display a different piece of content if the URL starts with the blog route (eg. /blog/.*) to every other request.